# ISSET GET / how to Ignore string entries that are not in DB

Tags: php, mysql, isset

I have an isset/get array that, if posted from a previous script, executes the script with the vars $state, $cat and $sub

MY QUESTION:  how do allow only isset($_GET entries in my mysql db to display and toss an error on all others that are not in my db ???

The below is a portion of an existing script that works well but I have shown it as example in order to try and understand how to disregard strings that are not in my database. Where it is currently allowing any string passed.

```
    if
    index.php?state=Washington 
        is changed to
    index.php?state=Hempville
```

The script still passes Hempville as a new instance in my final page.

I'm not a total n3wb and so thanks for any assistance.

example

```
$self = mysql_escape_string($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$state = mysql_escape_string($_GET['state']);
$cat = mysql_escape_string($_GET['cat']);
$sub = mysql_escape_string($_GET['sub']);
```

And, the isset/_GET routine is:

```
if (isset($_GET['state'], $_GET['cat'], $_GET['sub'])) {
echo "<h3>$state</h3>";

// Breadcrumb 
echo "<a href=\"./\">HOME</a> >> <a href=\"index.php?state=$state\">$state</a> >> <a href=\"#\">$cat</a> >> <a href=\"index3.php?cat=$catup&sub=$sub&state=$state\">$sub</a>";
```

Comment: Not sure what are you asking but maybe if(isset(isset($_GET['state']) && isset($_GET['cat']) && isset($_GET['sub'])){//do something

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to only allow states that are already in the database to be valid strings?

One way you could do this is just do a lookup (SELECT) for the state to ensure that it is in the database.

Example:
    (pesudo)

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE state='Washington';
if (count > 0) {
    // washington is a valid input
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate against your data set. You can do this in a number of ways:

For instance, set a session variable with acceptable values:

```
 if(!isset($_SESSION["acceptable_states"])) {  
    $q = "select distinct(state) from states_table";
    $r = mysql_query($q);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($r)) {
        $_SESSION["acceptable_states"][] = $row[0];
    }
}
```

Then for $_GET["state"] you would do:

```
if(in_array($_GET["state"], $_SESSION["acceptable_states"])) {
    //display page or whatever here
} else {
    echo 'No Such State';
}
```

Then do this for each variable.